# Child Portal Logout Issue

Tags: dotnetnuke

Currently we have single DNN installation with multiple sites in it. Some of them are created as parent, child portal. Recently we are facing logout issue on child portals for admin and registered user (not host users). When any Admin/Registered user logs in, in child site and try to perform any action e.g. edit any module or navigate to any page or even refresh the page, he gets logged out .

Points to note:

·         We are using DotNetNuke version 4.8.

·         Currently we have faced this issue for Pashto and Dari language child sites.

·         Prior to this we never faced this kind of problem for any child language sites including Portuguese, French and Arabic.

Initial Observation:

·         We also observer that for user with same username (profile) exists on both parent and child sites this issue doesn’t occur.

Thanks in advance,

Hari

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue in DNN 5.6.0, but it only manifested itself when we directly linked to an ASPX page from a child portal.

The problem is that with child portals, unless you have an alias in the url, there's no way to know what portal is accessing the file.

The solution was to append a ?PortalID=X to the url (X is the PortalID).

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but this info might help others.